# Класс, создание объекта, конструктор

Tags: java

Прочитал статьи, смотрю видео и заметил вот такую конструкцию:

```
 Animal animal = new Dog();
```

Где автор сказал: Объект класса Dog типа Animal.

Давайте разберем:

1. Animal - это класс
2. animal - это название объекта
3. new - ключевое слово, которое отвечает за создание объекта
4. Dog() - конструктор

Не пойму почему он сказал:

Объект класса Dog типа Animal.

Я привык вот к такому:

```
Animal animal = new Animal();
```

Почему у нас здесь создается объект класса Dog?

```
Animal animal = new Dog();
```

Если у нас класс и название Animal animal, а `new Dog()` получается создание конструктора или у нас `new Dog()` это значит создание объекта, тогда почему это создание объекта если у нас Dog() это конструктор? Почему создается объект?

Почему еще говорят класс это и есть объект?

Comment: Вероятно афтар статьи данным примером пытался научить читателя полиморфизму (в отличии от афтаров ответов, напирающих на наследование). Если Вам не понятен этот афтар, то поищите другого, более внятного. Потом станет понятно, что он хотел показать.

Comment: Да про полиморфизм, но посмотрел другого где я увидел переопределение методов и всё встало на свои места. Но вот эта конструкция не даёт покоя

Comment: Для работы полиморфизма вовсе не обязательно переопределять методы. Это несколько иное и параллельное переопределению. Я так считаю.

Comment: @Sergey да я уже устал от этого полиморфизма, везде разные реализации, в каждом языке свои фичи, на udemy.com в нормальных курсах показывается только переопределение методов, на собеседовании узнал что перегрузка не относится к полиморфизму в рамках ЯП Java, когда на одном сайте написано что это полиморфизм -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему у нас здесь создается объект класса Dog?

Потому что класс `Dog` скорее всего наследует класс `Animal`.

> тогда почему это создание объекта если у нас Dog() это конструктор?

`Dog` - не конструктор, а класс. Но при создании `animal` используется конструктор из класса `Dog`.

> Почему еще говорять класс это и есть объект?

Потому что классы описывают объекты.

---

`Animal animal = new Dog();` - создается ссылка на класс Dog типа `Animal`. Т.е., так же как у примитивной переменной тип `int`, у `animal` - тип `Animal`(но ссылается она все равно на `Dog`).

Для чего это надо? Приведу пример. У вас есть три класса: `Animal`, `Dog`, `Hourse`.

```
class Animal{
int speed;
boolean live;
String name;

public void speedUp() {speed++;}
}

class Dog() extends Animal{
   public Dog(int speed, boolean live, String name) {
      super.speed = speed;
      super.name = name;
      super.live = live;
   } 
}

class Hourse() {
    public Hourse(int speed, boolean live, String name) {
      super.speed = speed;
      super.name = name;
      super.live = live;
   } 
}
```

У вас нет необходимости переписывать все переменные и методы которые есть в `Animal` в класс `Hourse` и `Dog`.

Допустим, у вас есть список животных(пусть называется pen, с англ. - загон). И вам надо поместить в загон всех животных, и собак, и коров, и лошадей. Тогда вы просто объявляете список `ArrayList<Animal> pen = new ArrayList<>();`, и можете помещать туда всех животных(в нашем случае `animal`, хотя корректнее было бы назвать переменную `Dog`. Но не один объект `dog`, а объекты `hourse1`, `hourse2`, `dog10`, их классы наследуют класс `Animal`).

Пример с кодом:

```
ArrayList<Animal> pen = new ArrayList<>();

Animal hourse1 = new Hourse(0, true, "1"); 
Animal hourseBlack = new Hourse(); //не указываю параметры
Animal hoursePink = new Hourse();
Animal bigDog = new Dog();

pen.add(hourse1);
pen.add(hourseBlack);
pen.add(hoursePink);
pen.add(bigDog);
```

Это только одно преимущество использования полиморфизма. Другое, как я уже писал в статье - реюзабельность кода, когда вы можете в одном классе(`Animal`) прописать одинаковое поведение для наследников(`Dog`, `Hourse`). Поэтому вы можете сделать вот так: `hourse1.speedUp();` `bigDog.speedUp();`.

Comment: Если сделать так: `Dog eineKleineDog = new Dog(); pen.add(eineKleineDog);` разве не сработает?

Comment: Может моего eineKlineSobaken-а и в просто List поместить нельзя? Object->Animal->Dog

Comment: Решить спор может компиляция исходного кода. Мой компилятор позволяет мне сделать так, как я написал в своём комментарии выше:)

Comment: @Sergey да, извиняюсь. Вы оказались правы. Как вы считаете, было бы логично компилятору вести себя так, как я описывал?

Comment: Компилятор работает как раз так, как задумано. Это негодный пример полиморфизма. Ну на самом деле он показывает полиморфизм, но не Animal-а с Dog-ом, а ... массива pen :-o Полиморфизм в более широком смысле, чем обычно полагают маленькие любители ООП. Правильный пример - как обычно вызов одноимённой функции через ссылку на Animal. Ничего тут нового не придумаешь

Answer (score 1):

`Animal` - это суперкласс для каких-то (абстрактных) животных. `Dog` - его подкласс (дочерний). Поэтому мы можем объявлять переменную более абстрактного типа, создавая объекты разных подклассов. Это используется в полиморфизме, когда, например, мы хотим в список или массив поместить много животных (подклассов класса `Animal`) и оперировать ими, например, вызывать их метод `fly()`...

Еще пример, мы имеем интерфейс `interface Sort`, в котором прописан метод `sort(...)`. И у нас есть несколько классов, реализующих этот интерфейс (к примеру, `QuickSort`, `MergeSort` etc...). Тогда мы можем создать несколько переменных типа `Sort` и использовать их, подставляя в нужное место в зависимости от нужного нам алгоритма:

```
Sort sort;
sort = new MergeSort();
sort.sort(...); // используем алгоритм mergeSort
sort = new QuickSort();
sort.sort(...); // используем алгоритм quickSort
```